# What is Apple's take on using hidden icons from UIKit

Tags: ios, uikit, icons, app-store

There is a project on GitHub ([UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/)) that extracts images from UIKit. What is Apple's take on when using these images in your application. I'm planning to use the exclamation mark icon when a message is not successfully sent for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no difference between extract the icons from the UIKit or to create exactly the same icon in graphic editor. In the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) guidelines is written:

> Avoid using iOS interface elements in your artwork. You don’t want
>   users to confuse your icons or images with the iOS UI.

But if you want to use for example Action button image or Back button image, I think it is completely OK if it does exactly, what the user expects.

Hope it helps